# Dictionary - synonyms

Tags: sed, cut, join, tr

I have czech czech-finnish dictionary and I have two czech synonyms in one row.

Example:

```
záchod (m); toaleta (f) WC; käymälä; miestenhuone; naistenhuone; vessa
```

Synonyms are divided by semicolon and I would like, if the next word(synonym) would be on the next row.

Like this:

```
toaleta (f)     WC; käymälä; miestenhuone; naistenhuone; vessa
záchod (m)      WC; käymälä; miestenhuone; naistenhuone; vessa
```

Comment: so, you want to know if this `WC; käymälä; miestenhuone; naistenhuone; vessa` section of the line is the same on the next line same location. Is that right ? Your question is not very clear

Comment: In the first column can be at least one czech word. If there are two and more czech words, which have same meaning in finnish language, I would like to put them on the next row.

Comment: "toaleta" and "záchod" are synonyms and I want to put "záchod" on the next row with the same meaning in finnish language, which has toaleta.

Comment: what is the indication that, those two words are synonyms ? the `(m)` and the `(f)` strings ? If yes, are there any others ? In order to accomplish, there has to be a matching pattern on lines you want to split in to two lines (or may be more). Things may be clear to you but a heavy majority of the users of this site do not posses language skills in any of those two languages

Comment: Every czech synonym in the left column has on the end this ([m,n,f])

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a bit of perl. I modified your input a bit to test single and triple czech words:

```
$ cat dictionary 
záchod (m); toaleta (f) WC; käymälä; miestenhuone; naistenhuone; vessa
single (f) WC; test; words; go; here
first (f); second (n); third (m) WC; singleton


$ cat word_per_line.pl 
open($dictionary, '<', "./$ARGV[0]");

while( $word = <$dictionary> ) {
    $word =~ /(.*) (WC;.*)/;
    @czech = split(/; /, $1);
    foreach (@czech) {
        print "$_\t$2\n";
    }
}

$ perl word_per_line.pl dictionary 
záchod (m)  WC; käymälä; miestenhuone; naistenhuone; vessa
toaleta (f) WC; käymälä; miestenhuone; naistenhuone; vessa
single (f)  WC; test; words; go; here
first (f)   WC; singleton
second (n)  WC; singleton
third (m)   WC; singleton
```